# Sequelize: Wrong column names on junction table columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a MySQL database where everything is in `snake_case`. I have two models with many-to-many relationship (`RoomBooking` and `User`), and one manually-defined model (called `MeetingGuest`) that acts as their junction table (among other things). The problem is, Sequelize keeps generating queries with `PascalCase` column and table names for this junction model.

`MeetingGuest` is generated using `sequelize-cli`, and tweaked to become like so:

```js
const { Model } = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class MeetingGuest extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {

    }
  }
  MeetingGuest.init(
    {
      room_booking_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'RoomBooking',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'User',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      status: DataTypes.STRING,
      check_in: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'MeetingGuest',
      tableName: 'meeting_guests',
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    },
  )
  return MeetingGuest
}
```

The query it generates is like this:

```sql
SELECT
MeetingGuest.RoomBookingId,   -- `room_booking_id` is never aliased into RoomBookingId
-- Other selected columns...
FROM `users` AS `User`
INNER JOIN `meeting_guests` AS `MeetingGuest`
ON `User`.`id` = `MeetingGuest`.`UserId` AND `MeetingGuest`.`RoomBookingId` = 1;
```

Comment: Please add association definitions

Comment: I don't define associations. If I define association, it'll just query the `user` table.

Comment: Please show the Sequelize query that gives you that SQL query. And of course you have at least one association between `User` and `MeetingGuest` to be able to join them in Sequelize query

Answer (score 1):

Defining the foreign keys explicitly is the key.

I went from

```js
modelA.belongsToMany(modelB,
  { through: associativeTable }
);
modelB.belongsToMany(modelA,
  { through: associativeTable }
);
```

to

```js
modelA.belongsToMany(modelB,
  { through: associativeTable, foreignKey: 'modelA_id' }
);
modelB.belongsToMany(modelA,
  { through: associativeTable, foreignKey: 'modelB_id' }
);
```

And now everything is peachy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to add `foreignKey` and `otherKey` to the model to be associated with. In my case, it's `RoomBooking` (*not* the join table). Like this:

```js
const { Model } = require('sequelize')
const User = require('./User')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class RoomBooking extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.Room, {
        foreignKey: 'room_id',
      })
      this.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'host',
      })
      this.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: models.MeetingGuest,
        foreignKey: 'room_booking_id',
        otherKey: 'user_id',
        as: 'guests',
      })
    }
  }
  RoomBooking.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'User',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      room_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      // ...other fields
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'RoomBooking',
      tableName: 'room_bookings',
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    },
  )
  return RoomBooking
}
```